# TabBar Stop The Popping

Tags: iphone, navigation, tabbar

If have a Navigation Bar and a Tab Bar in one of my views.
This is all working fine.
One of the Tab Bar items requires pushing several other view controllers on the navigation stack before I get the where I need to be.
This is also working.
When I click on the tab bar item, it marches right back up the stack.
How can I make the desired controller stick in the tab bar item?

Comment: Just as an aside, you don't click things on the iPhone, you tap them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard behaviour of the Tab Bar, if you set it up with each tab pointing to a different view controller in the main nib file.  It is in fact quite useful, allowing the user to navigate deeply within a particular stack, and then press the tab button that's already selected to return to the home/top level.

Note that this behaviour only happens when you click on a tab that you already have selected.  You could implement a line in the tab bar delegate that intercepts the click on a tab and disregards it if that tab is already selected.

To do this you'll need to handle the display of different view controllers manually.  You want to implement this method:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

and then push different views onto the navigation stacks yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
You cannot change the appdelegate for the tab when in a NavigationController.  I was able to do the same thing by overriding
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tbController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)vwController